# Button action is not working ios 10, swift 3, xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, ios10, xcode8

I have Button in VC in storyboard and I am able to use outlet of it and it is working fine. when it comes to action, it is not working.

find the images for reference.

```
@IBAction func actionStart(_ sender: Any) {

    if (isStarted == false)
    {
        isStarted = true
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
        {
            self.tripTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(LandingViewController.displayTripTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
}
```

View Hierarchy:

[image: View Hierarchy]

IBOutlet Connection:

[image: IBOutlet Connections]

Comment: Give the background color of MapView and Button. May be your constraint are not set perfectly and they overlap each other.

Comment: use show touch on highlight  on button to check it clicked or not.

Comment: show your constraints, because of your constraint it may possible that your button is hidden behind another controller as @RajniJoharRaswant said!

Comment: Simply print anything in your button action then apply functionality.

Comment: Are you even able to press your button? Isn't somehow your subview overlapping the buttons?

Comment: What exactly happens " it is not working"? Is `actionStart` actually called?

Comment: Constraints are perfect. Even button action is not working with empty view controller (separately i took new one)